# Covariance of $X$, $Y^2$?

Tags: covariance

I have an expression in terms of the empirical covariance of $(X,Y)$, where X and Y are two variables in some data that I have. I want to be able to say what happens to this expression as a function of the covariance of $(X,Y^2)$. Anyone have any ideas?

Is this underspecified? If so, what other information do I need?